# Webpack to copy files and convert path aliases ONLY

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-4

I have a large component library, made from single file VUE files.

```
/src/
    /a.vue
    /b.vue
    /sub/
        /c.vue
```

And I'd like to export it like this:

```
/src/
    /a.js
    /b.js
    /sub/
        /c.js
```

Babel does convert the JS files to ES5, but it doesn't (obviously) convert the VUE files to js.

Is there a way to use Vue-CLI or webpack directly to transpile this?

FYI: I specifically want to avoid single file packed results.

Comment: Have you added Vue Loader's plugin?

Comment: of course.  I can build, but I have only figured out how to build to packed single js files.